# CSS, Picture gallery in a row, space between each picture,

Tags: css, spacing

Hello i am trying to add some space between pictures in a row, as well in the column. here is my code. I would really appreciate if you would point me in right direction

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body
 { 
    background-color:#abe9ff;
}
.container {
  width: 950px; /* look i'm now showing 4 images per line */  
  margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
 }
.img {
 /* height: 234px; width: 218px; */
 float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 10px;

}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div img src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234"      href="boywonder.htm">
 <img src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234"   href="boywonder.htm">
 <img src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">
 <img src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">
 <img src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: firstly your divs should be closed.

Comment: yeye it was accidentaly deleted when posting otherwise i am having it

Answer (score -1):

use this html

```
<body >

<div id="wrapper">

<div class="container">

 <img class="image" src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234"     href="boywonder.htm">
 <img class="image" src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">
 <img class="image" src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">
 <img class="image" src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">
 <img class="image" src="interpret_1.png" alt="Interpret1" width="218" height="234" href="boywonder.htm">
</div>



</div>


</body>
```

and css goes like

```
body{   margin:0 5px;
}


#wrapper
{ 
background-color:#abe9ff;
        height:500px;}

.container { width:950px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}


.image{
 height: 234px; width: 218px; 
 float: left;
margin-top:10px;

margin-right: 19px;}
```